# Capacitance of a negative conductor

Tags: charge, capacitance

Well we know that Capacitance of a Capacitor is Charge on it by Potential Difference between the 2 Conductors

If charge on the capacitor is negative then the Capacitance of the conductor will be negative

Can Capacitance of a Capacitor be negative?

Answer (score 1):

You should stop and think what do you mean by "charge on it". 
Normally, the total charge on a capacitor is zero as the two plates will have equal and opposite charges. So your definition (or the way you formulate it) is not quite proper for the purpose.

When the capacitance is defined for a parallel plate capacitor, the charge in the formula 
                          C=Q/V 
is the magnitude of the charge of one of the pates and "V" is not the potential but the potential difference between the plates. This is also taken as a magnitude.

For a more general meaning of the definition, when capacitance is defined for a single object, like a metallic sphere, both Q and V can be negative or positive but they have the same sign, as mentioned already in the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

if we consider the two plate parallel capacitor and having negative charge on the one of the plate then due  to net charge on the capacitor is zero it induce opposite charge of same magnitude on the other plate.
 as we know we measure potential difference by subtracting the potential on the positive plate to the potential to the negative plate so potential diff. being positive the capacitance of the capacitor is always positive not negative